# Cross reference columns in Parse to decide which users to Display on a view controller. Swift, user search settings

Tags: ios, swift, search, parse-platform, swift2

What I am trying to figure out is how to only display users that meet the setting requirements that the user previously saved on a different `ViewController`. Ok so on set up the current user has selected their genre and instrument and it has saved in columns in `Parse` called "genre" and "instrument" as Strings. Then on the search settings page the user has selected that they would like to search for lets say "Rock" as the genre and "Acoustic guitar" as the instrument. Both of these then get added to Parse under the columns "genreSearch" and "instrumentSearch".

So I know I need to make a query and display it on the `ViewController` that the users are displayed on but I don't know how. I am trying to basically cross reference the column "genre" of other users against the current users column "genreSearch". I imagined it would be something like this:

```
genreQuery.whereKey("username",notEqualTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
genreQuery.whereKey("genre", notEqualTo:PFUser.currentUser()!username!)        
genreQuery.whereKey("genreSearch", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)        
genreQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (users: [AnyObject]?,   
error: NSError?) -> Void in

if error == nil {
    for user in users! {

        if self.genre == self.genreSearch {

            print("These two strings are considered equal")

            appUsers.append(user as! PFUser)

        }  
    self.resultsPageTableView.reloadData()`
```

At the top of my `VC` I have as I am storing and displaying all the users in a cell which also links to another `VC` to show more details.

```
var genre = [String]()
var genreSearch = [String]()
var appUsers = [PFUser]()
```

I have read `Parse` docs and to be honest now I am more confused as where to go.
I have searched the internet for past few days and it is all js and objc both of which I have zero experience in. If someone could point me at a start or even guide me in what to do so I can learn.

In the cell I am displaying the users details like so:

```
 let singleCell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mySingleCellid") as! CustomCell

 let userObject = appUsers[indexPath.row] as PFObject

 singleCell.userName.text = userObject["name"] as? String
// etc  
return singleCell
```

Comment: Why are you saving `genreSearch`? If you do you need to use a `whereQuery`

Comment: I was saving the genreSearch as a way to save to Parse the search setting that the user had chosen. Is there a better way to save settings like this? Like the user has chosen to search profiles that have the genre "Rock" in them. So the UsersFeed will only show profiles that have chosen "Rock" as their genre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going about it all wrong what I needed to do was take genreSearch from the Parse DB and store it in the app itself as a variable. This variable is then a key for my PFQuery and I use it to filter out the people that don't have it. I then use genreSearch as a condition skipping the people that don't have it and adding the people that do. I nearly have it cracked except for the last few coding of it. Instead of editing this question to ask for help I have asked and posted my new code to a new [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595934/using-a-variable-as-a-key-for-a-pfquery-to-filter-out-users-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This part of the query

```
genreQuery.whereKey("genreSearch", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
```

is wrong because you're trying to check that an array of strings contains a user object (a pointer) - which will always fail.

While you have genreSearch on the server for the current user it's easier to just replace that part of the query with

```
genreQuery.whereKey("genreSearch", containedIn:PFUser.currentUser()!["genreSearch"])
```

which instead asks for the genreSearch array on each user tested to contain at least one of the current users array of genreSearch

Comment: So on changing the line above the only way it would work was by changing it to this ` genreQuery.whereKey("genreSearch", containedIn:(PFUser.currentUser()!["genreSearch"] as! [AnyObject]?)!)` but when segue to the VC it crashes with the error: Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x19f42bf20) to 'NSArray' (0x19f42bfc0) I do get what you are saying though but my genreSearch column is not a pointer to I need to make it a pointer in order for it to work?

Comment: it isn't a pointer though right, you're setting it to an array of strings? though that error indicates it is a pointer, so i'm not exactly sure how you set its value

Comment: No its definitely not a pointer, just regular columns. 'genre' String and 'genreSearch' String. Is how they both appear in the Parse column