# Using a variable as a key for a PFQuery to filter out users. Swift Querying a User

Tags: swift, parse-platform, nsstring, swift2, pfquery

Variable in a User class as a string. Using this variable as a key for a PFQuery and use it to filter out the users that don't have it.I need to skip users that don't have it and add the users that do to the VC display. Here is my code so far: 
In the VC where the variable is stored I have:

```
var genreSearch: NSString?
```

after viewDidLoad in a cell I have:

```
    let genreSearch = table_data[indexPath.row]

    userDefaults.setObject(genreSearch, forKey: "genre")
    print(genreSearch)`
```

Then on the VC where the query is being called I have:

```
    if let genreSearch = userDefaults.objectForKey("genre") as? [String] {
        // do something here when a genresearch exists

        let genreQuery = PFUser.query()

        genreQuery!.whereKey("genre", containedIn: (genreSearch as [String]))

        genreQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (users: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


            if error == nil {
                // success


                for user in users! {
                    self.appUsers.append(user as! PFUser)
                } // users


                self.resultsPageTableView.reloadData()

            } // error
            else {
        }

        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been stuck on this genreSearch query for what feels like weeks!!!

Also here is my code on VC2 that is updating the users info in a cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let singleCell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mySingleCellid") as! CustomCell

    let userObject = appUsers[indexPath.row] as PFObject


    singleCell.userName.text = userObject["name"] as? String
```

So I have edited my code as I figured out the errors that were being called ***I am able to open the VC but it does not filter out the results? It displays all the users instead of skipping the users that haven't got the chosen genre. Any ideas??? ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out why it was not filtering out my users!!!

On the VC where the variable was stored I was missing a vital line above the class :

```
var genreSearch: String?

let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()  //this one
```

Then in the ResultsVC I added:

```
if let genre = userDefaults.stringForKey("genre")  //this line

    {

        print(genre)

        let genreQuery = PFUser.query()


        genreQuery?.whereKey("username",notEqualTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        genreQuery!.whereKey("genre", equalTo: genre)                    

genreQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (genres: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                // success

                self.appUsers.removeAll()

                for genre in genres! {

                  self.appUsers.append(genre as! PFUser)

                } // users

                  }

                self.resultsPageTableView.reloadData()

                self.refresher.endRefreshing()

            } // error
```

I think it just wasn't saving or doing anything with the userDefaults on VC1 I must have missed a step!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make a query on the User table provided by parse, you should use instead of `let genreQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")`

```
let genreQuery = PFUser.query()
```

Comment: Ya I tried it that way and it returns the same results, sorry I should have mentioned that in my question.